# Construir aplicação Móvel baseada em aplicação Web

Tags: php, web-service, mobile, jquery-mobile, pwa

Boa noite pessoal, estou participando de um projeto voluntário a um grupo e temos uma aplicação Web pronta, desenvolvida em PHP com o framework Laravel. Precisamos que um formulário de inclusão de dados dessa aplicação seja criada também para ambientes móveis, pois os usuários devem utilizar também enquanto estiverem se locomovendo, pois, mesmo que tenham ausência de rede, ou a mesma seja inconsistente, seria realizado o cadastro dos dados pelo aplicativo (numa forma de trabalho offline) e o mesmo sincronizaria com o servidor.

Já desenvolvi um protótipo de uma PWA de um bloco de notas que criei em javascript, css e html, buscando uma abordagem hibrida, porem o resultado no IOS não foi como esperado, e ainda não sei se partir para um PWA seria a melhor abordagem.

Portanto gostaria de ajuda nos seguintes pontos:

- Como já tenho o back-end desenvolvido para a aplicação Web, consigo reaproveitar o mesmo? e como funcionaria?
- Estava pesquisando também a ferramenta firebase da Google para a sincronização dos dados
- Conseguiria por meio de um web service realizar a comunicação dos dados? alguma dica a respeito?

Se alguém  tiver alguma experiencia no assunto ficarei muito grato com ajuda, pode ter uma maneira mais objetiva de se realizar, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Utilize o [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/), [Phonegap](https://phonegap.com/) ou [Nativescript](https://www.nativescript.org/) para fazer a sua aplicação híbrida. Eu recomendaria utilizar um WebView ([Ios](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) ou [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)) por você já possuir uma aplicação Web, porém se você quer guardar os dados caso o usuário esteja offline, o Webview não possuí esse recurso. Com as plataformas híbridas citadas você consegue guardar essas informações até que o dispositivo acesse a internet novamente.

No Ionic pude encontrar uma solução rápida e fácil para utilizar o recurso chamada [Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/). "O Ionic Storage é uma maneira simples de armazenar dados no formato chave/valor seja em um PWA (Progressive Web App) ou em um aplicativo nativo." 
Fonte: [Como armazenar dados offline com Ionic Storage](http://www.fabricadecodigo.com/como-armazenar-dados-offline-com-ionic-storage/)

Espero ter ajudado. Um abraço!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta fabio, utilizando o Ionic eu consigo reaproveitar parte do back-end já desenvolvido?

Comment: Sim! Porém, você irá precisar de criar uma camada Restful. Ou seja, vai precisar implementar a autenticação (se houver), e métodos que retornem os dados em JSON para manipulação dos dados no Front-end. Espero ter ajudado!